# Graphical glitches after waking from sleep

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend, kwin

### **Description of issue**

Graphical glitches appear after the computer wakes from sleep. They look like large triangles of varied colors and sometimes still display some of the graphical elements behind them. I am no longer able to interact with anything on the screen. I can temporarly regain access by following the temporary fix below. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdXCr.jpg

### **Steps to reproduce**

1. Allow computer to go to sleep.
2. Wake up the computer.
3. At first it is fine, but after unminimizing a program the graphical glitches appear.

### **Temporary fix**

After glitches appear, I can reset kwin by holding ctrl+alt+f2 (screen goes black) and then ctrl+alt+f1. This reset fixes the glitches, but once another program is unminimized the glitches reappear. Once a particular program has been unminimized once, it no longer produces the glitch if minimized and unminimized again. If the computer is restarted the glitches do not occur until after waking from sleep again.

### **PC description**

**OS**: Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64

**Kernel**: 5.15.0-53-generic

**DE**: Plasma 5.24.6

**WM**: KWin

**CPU**: 12th Gen Intel i9-12900K (24) @ 5.200GHz

**GPU**: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090

**GPU**: Intel AlderLake-S GT1

**Memory**: 5884MiB / 64096MiB

### **Logs**

Systemd log surrounding the suspend and wake operations: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/88yRmHqxX2/

Nvidia bug report log: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Md7YwDd2Nr/

KWin support info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vzbTpCMzqC/

Any help would be appreciated! Not really sure where to start with troubleshooting this further.

Comment: Hi @kanehekili, the OS and kernel versions are already in my original post.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the exact same issue. I'm using Manjaro KDE on Nvidia 1080Ti. I think this is specifically an Nvidia issue, possibly related to KDE.